# can't start application with foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreman

I have a `Procfile` like this

```
web: bundle exec puma  
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
```

when I try to start my app, I got this

```
15:13:30 web.1    | /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find bundler (>= 0) amongst [Ascii85-1.0.1, actionmailer-3.2.6, actionpack-3.2.6, activemodel-3.2.6, activerecord-3.2.6, activeresource-3.2.6, activesupport-3.2.6, archive-tar-minitar-0.5.2, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bigdecimal-1.1.0, bootstrap-will_paginate-0.0.7, bson-1.6.4, bson_ext-1.6.4, cancan-1.6.8, carrierwave-0.6.2, carrierwave-mongoid-0.2.1, carrierwave-mongoid-0.1.0, celluloid-0.11.1, childprocess-0.3.2, chunky_png-1.2.5, ckeditor-3.7.0.rc3, ckeditor-3.6.3, ckeditor-rails-0.0.3, ckeditor_rails-3.6.3.1, ckeditor_rails-3.6.3, ckeditor_rails-3.6.2.2, client_side_validations-3.2.0.beta.6, client_side_validations-3.1.4, client_side_validations-mongoid-2.4.0.beta.2, coffee-rails-3.2.2, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.3.3, coffee-script-source-1.3.2, coffee-script-source-1.3.1, commonjs-0.2.5, compass-0.12.2, compass-rails-1.0.3, connection_pool-0.9.2, cookiejar-0.3.0, devise-2.1.2, devise-2.1.1, devise-2.1.0, devise-2.0.4, em-http-request-1.0.2, em-socksify-0.2.0, eventmachine-1.0.0.beta.4, excon-0.14.2, excon-0.14.1, excon-0.13.4, execjs-1.4.0, execjs-1.3.0, fancybox-rails-0.1.4, faye-0.8.2, faye-websocket-0.4.5, ffi-1.0.11, fog-1.4.0, fog-1.3.1, foreman-0.51.0, foreman-0.48.0, formatador-0.2.3, formatador-0.2.2, formatador-0.2.1, fssm-0.2.9, hashr-0.0.21, http_parser.rb-0.5.3, io-console-0.3, ios-checkboxes-0.2.1, journey-1.0.4, jquery-rails-2.0.2, jruby-pageant-1.0.2, json-1.7.3, json-1.5.4, less-2.1.0, less-rails-2.2.3, less-rails-2.2.1, mime-types-1.19, mime-types-1.17.2, minitest-2.5.1, mongoid-3.0.3, mongoid-3.0.0.rc, mongoid-2.4.12, mongoid-2.4.11, mongoid-2.4.10, mongoid_slug-0.10.0, moped-1.2.0, moped-1.0.0, mousetrapjs-0.0.7, mousetrapjs-0.0.6, mousetrapjs-0.0.5, multi_json-1.3.6, multi_json-1.3.5, nested_form-0.2.0, net-scp-1.0.4, net-ssh-2.5.2, net-ssh-2.4.0, net-ssh-2.3.0, nokogiri-1.5.5, nokogiri-1.5.4, nokogiri-1.5.3, nokogiri-1.5.2, origin-1.0.1, orm_adapter-0.4.0, orm_adapter-0.3.0, orm_adapter-0.1.0, orm_adapter-0.0.7, pdf-reader-1.1.0, prawn-0.12.0, prawn_rails-0.0.8, puma-1.5.0, quiet_assets-1.0.1, rabl-0.7.0, rabl-0.6.14, rabl-0.6.13, rabl-0.6.12, rabl-0.6.11, rack-1.2.1, rack-protection-1.2.0, rails-3.2.6, rails-i18n-0.6.3, railties-3.2.6, raindrops-0.10.0, raindrops-0.9.0, raindrops-0.8.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdiscount-1.6.8, rdoc-3.9.4, redis-namespace-1.0.3, resque-1.20.0, ruby-hmac-0.4.0, ruby-rc4-0.1.5, rubygems-update-1.8.22, sass-3.1.19, sass-3.1.18, sass-3.1.17, sass-3.1.16, sass-rails-3.2.5, sidekiq-2.1.0, sinatra-1.3.2, sinatra-1.0, sprockets-2.1.3, sqlite3-1.3.6, stringex-1.4.0, thin-1.3.1, thor-0.15.4, thor-0.15.3, timers-1.0.1, tire-0.4.2, ttfunk-1.0.3, twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.1.1, uglifier-1.2.7, uglifier-1.2.6, uglifier-1.2.5, uglifier-1.2.4, vanities-0.1.3, vegas-0.1.11, warden-1.2.1, warden-1.1.1, will_paginate-3.0.3, will_paginate_mongoid-1.0.5, yajl-ruby-1.1.0, yajl-ruby-0.7.7, zurb-foundation-2.2.1.2] (Gem::LoadError)
```

I've already tried running `bundle`, `bundle install`, `bundle update` and `gem install bundler`
What is going on with this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you starting foreman with `bundle exec foreman start`?

Comment: When i start with `bundle exec` i got this: `15:24:41 worker.1 | /home/luiz/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.5/lib/bundler/source.rb:574:in `rescue in load_spec_files': git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
`

Comment: LOL, got the same error error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
bundle pack --all
bundle install
```